# Keycloak email verification not working and receiving any email through keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am Using keycloak 4.5.0 v and created a realm. I have set up the login to enable forget username and verify email. In the email tab I entered

```
host - smtp.gmail.com  
smtp port:465 
username - ***@gmail.com 
SSL/TLS - enabled 
Authentication - enabled with username and password
```

But I'm still unable to connect to gmail it always pop fail to send email notification error shown:

> 14:53:14,070 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource] (default task-1) Failed to send email
>    com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout 10000;
>     nested exception is:
>           java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Any Help would be highly appreciated thank u

Comment: The error is pretty obvious: the sever running keycloak can't connect to host `smtp.gmail.com` on port `465`.  Check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

change smtp port to 587 i think this work and off SSl and TLS is on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).